# How to inspect the number of events on a Kafka topic using the CLI?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have lost access to Conduktor. (The free version doesn't support multi-broker clusters beyond the trial period.)

I also can't get a license because their website doesn't permit enquiries from non-enterprise email addresses.

I want to inspect the number of events / messages on each Topic / Partition using the Kafka CLI tools.

I couldn't figure out how to do that.

- `./kafka-topics.sh --describe` shows the topics, partition breakdown, leaders, replicas and ISR. It does not show offsets or watermarks.
- `./kafka-get-offsets.sh` shows the offsets for each partition, but this isn't the same as the number of messages, since the topic might have been cleared, meaning the lowest offset might not be zero.

Comment: As an aside, I'm thinking about starting a side project to build an electron app interface for Kafka, as an Open Source project to replace/improve on what is offered by Conduktor. Conduktor is generally quite good but can be a bit clunky. If anyone wants to help me with this please reach out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of messages in each partition, you can use the `kafka-run-class` tool to run the `kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell` method. For each topic and partition, you can get the earliest and latest offsets, which indicate the number of messages.

Here's how you can get the latest offset (which essentially is the number of messages) for each partition:

```
kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list <broker_host>:<broker_port> --topic <topic_name> --time -1
```

In the above command, `--time -1` gets the latest offset. If you want to get the earliest offset, you can use `--time -2`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this great answer! I note that `./kafka-run-class.sh --list-modules` can be used to find a list of modules, but do you know how more info on each module can be found? Is there any online documentation?

Comment: Great. There isn't too much in terms of documentation out there to the best of my knowledge. You could try using `--help` in the command to see if that provides more information